# Clean Architecture: Loading data for the domain layer

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

Let's say my domain has a `User` Entity that has a many to many relationship with itself representing "Friends"

```cs
public class User
{
    public int Id;
    public IEnumerable<User>? Friends;
}
```

In my application layer, I have a service that makes 2 User friend together and the only requirement is that they are not already friends:

```cs
public class UserServies
{
    public void AddFriend(int user1Id, int user2Id)
    {
        var user1 = _repository.GetUserById(user1Id);
        var user2 = _repository.GetUserById(user2Id);
        // use user1 and user2 in my domain layer to enforce business rules... 
    }
}
```

`GetUserById` would execute a SQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT u.* FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Users_Friends uf ON u.Id = uf.UserId
LEFT JOIN Users f ON f.Id = uf.FriendId
WHERE u.Id = @Id
```

So far so good! But let's say the requirements changed and I would now need to access `user1.Friends[i].Friends`, this would result in a runtime error since we didn't load that data. I'm having trouble designing the domain layer in a way to avoid these kind of problems. I've thought of a few solutions, but none that makes me happy:

**Eagerly load all relationships all the time**

Bad: Performance wise it's terrible as it would require me to load all users all the time.

**Only load the necessary data required by my domain business rules**

Bad: This require way too much coupling between the data loader and the domain rules using said data. It would also be incredibly easy for a business rules change to result in a runtime error because someone didn't realize that the data loaded was no longer adequate (such as in my example above).

**Use lazy loading in domain layer**

Bad: Now the domain layer is no longer pure and is coupled to whatever persistence mechanism the infrastructure is using.

**Use specific DAO object for each business operations**

In this solution instead of dealing with a `User`, `AddFriend` would be dealing with a `AddFriendUserDAO`. `AddFriendUserDAO` would also need to have all its relationships be specific `AddFriend` DAO for it to works. Needless to say, it would increase the amount of code I need to write exponentially.

Do you have any recommended design pattern to deal with this scenario? I feel like it should be a pretty common scenario but I just don't know the right words to search for the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to point out: the added difficulty here is that you have a secret link between your different domain aggregates. If you load Tom as a person (which includes their friend list), and you also load Andy (which includes their friend list), and Tom now adds Andy as a friend, that means that you're expecting Andy's list to update and suddenly also contain Tom. This is not something you will find prescribed in general DDD documentation as it is a very special case. I haven't had the time to investigate for a full answer but I suspect that you will need to make friendships have their own context.

Comment: Well it's a made up situation, I mostly tried to come up with the simplest example. The question isn't about this specific scenario but more about how to deal with the fact that objects will always be partially loaded and the domain layer needs to be in sync with the infrastructure layer in order to avoid error

Comment: The point I was getting at is that this is a problem of your own making, this is a nested structure that is very likely an infinite one (to the point of exhaustion of having loaded all your users).  You don't want this, but you also don't want any of the additional work that the alternatives present. Something's gotta give, and we can't decide which poison is best to pick. There are myriad ways of modeling this and I'm not convinced that the current question is focused enough towards a particular approach. Every approach has wildly different pros and cons and this requires more analysis.

Comment: What I have found that helps is not holding the whole objects, just the ids. Ask yourself why you actually need to describe your domain entity with all the friends' objects. Where exactly does your BL use it? is it common or do you only use it occasionally? Your User entity has friends, ok, but what if the entity itself will hold only the ids of the friends?

Comment: @oren what you’re describing is how the web works. A page points at other pages using links. And that’s fine here so long as asymmetric friends are ok. Alice considers Bob a friend. But Bob doesn’t know who Alice is.

Comment: @oren: OOP and reference types makes it perfectly possible to load the actual user object themselves even if they are infinitely recursive (Bob is Tom's friend who is Bob's friend who is Tom's friend who is ...). The trick isn't in modeling the domain object, it's in knowing what to load when. I'd be careful about the "just use a FK ID" approach as this can start leaking the persistence implementation into the domain. I'm not saying it can't be done, but it's not necessarily the right call to make.

Comment: @MyUsername112358 do you need this "friend's friend's friend's..." information for a read operation (display something on the screen) or a write operation (enforce some business rules)? This read-write axis is usually a good leverage point for perf improvements - see CQRS approach.

Comment: I almost exclusively use the domain layer for write operations, and yes I'm already implementing the CQRS pattern but I don't see how that is relevant to how I design my domain layer?

Comment: My bad, I overlooked the fact that the question was exclusively about a write operation.

Answer (score 2):

The general approach here is going to be to *model* the interaction taking place. That is, make the implicit explicit. Let us add an additional concept to this system, `FriendRequest`, to carry some of that knowledge we are trying to crunch.

Here is an example of the general approach to use. I've extended our invariants to include an optional expiry and a max retry count to further exemplify how this approach can easily be extended to capture other constraints (and because "does something already exist" often doesn't *feel* like the kind of constraint that needs to be modeled explicitly as it is easily derived):

```
public class FriendRequest 
{
    public int senderId;
    public int receiverId;
    public int retryCount;
    public int? sentAt;
    public int? expiresAt;
    public int? acceptedAt;

    public void send(int? ttl) 
    {
        if (this.acceptedAt != null) throw new AlreadyFriends();
        if (this.retryCount + 1 > MAX_RETRY_COUNT) throw new GiveUpAlready();     

        this.sentAt = ...
        this.expiresAt = ...
        this.retryCount = ...
    }

    public void accept() 
    {
        if (this.sentAt == null) throw new NeverSent();
        if (this.isExpired) throw new Expired();
        if (this.acceptedAt != null) throw new AlreadyFriends();

        this.acceptedAt = ...
    }
}

public class UserService
{
    private FriendRequestRepository friends; //.find will return an "unsent" FriendRequest provided both users exist

    public void sendFriendRequest(int senderId, int receiverId)
    {
        var req = friends.find(senderId, receiverId); // may throw FriendRequestNotFound/UserNotFound
        req.send(FRIEND_REQUEST_TTL);
        friends.save(req);
    }

    public void acceptFriendRequest(int senderId, int receiverId)
    {
        var req = friends.find(senderId, receiverId); // may throw FriendRequestNotFound/UserNotFound
        req.accept(); 
        friends.save(req);
    }
}
```

There are other, similar, ways to organize the logic but the above should get the gears turning. Notice we didn't need to load *any* lists of friends! (and also arrived at a very terse, simple representation of our domain/rules)

The key concept here is to convert our rules into *data* (in this case our `retryCount`/`sentAt`/`acceptedAt`/`expiresAt`) that can then be used by our domain. This process is extensible to nearly any rule you can dream up. You want to check friends multiple layers deep? Project a `isIndirectlyFriendsAlready` field to our `FriendRequest`.

By representing our invariant with data we can then separate how/where we produce that data from how/where it is used. How could we add an expiry or retry counts to `AcceptFriendRequest(User user1, User user2, List<User> user1Friends, List<User> user2Friends)`? Are you going to enforce the same thing in `SendFriendRequest`? How? It becomes a mess.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question and does not help with business rules like "to add a friend you need to have less than 2 separations of friendship". In general adding your business rules as database constraint ONLY is really not recommended, your business / domain layer SHOULD also be clear about the requirements.

Comment: @MyUsername112358 The answer above is "the recommended design pattern to deal with this scenario", and provides a solution to the problem in accordance to the constraint you provided (though I added an additional constraint to exemplify how the solution may be extended). Do you want me to update my answer to handle your new constraint as well? More generally, do you think it's possible (or advisable) to model this system such that it can easily handle *any arbitrary* constraint? And to your last point, your repository interface is part of your domain. Time to be pragmatic.

Comment: The repository interface CAN BE part of the domain (does not have to be), but not the implementation. Hence business rules should absolutely not be found in your repository. Your solution is not pragmatic, it is simply wrong. @oren suggestion in the comment is actually pragmatic and fits my requirements

Comment: @MyUsername112358 The suggestion to only store lists of ids does not solve this problem in a general way. At a small enough scale with the right access patterns, sure, but I meant to provide a general answer to "how can I model a set constraint without loading my entire database". The answer, unfortunately, is that DDD doesn't play well with set theory, and you will have to make a tradeoff. You plan to lazy load then? FWIW it's trivial to change this design to keep the rule in the domain (still without loading friend lists), but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader!

Comment: @MyUsername112358 At the other commenter's request, I've edited my answer to show how we can keep the rule in our domain (and still be optimally efficient).

Comment: How does storing the list of ids not solve this problem in a general way? My approach is to load the objects and their relationships (but only the needed relationships) in the service layer and then provide that data to my domain layer. For instance my domain layer would have a method `AcceptFriendRequest(User user1, User user2, List<User> user1Friends, List<User> user2Friends)`. That way I never get the risk of having incomplete data objects and my business rules are all in the domain layer.

Comment: @MyUsername112358 "but only the needed relationships" - this is not general bc it is invariant dependent. I'm not saying your approach is wrong, but it clearly has constraints that my general solution does not. What happens if one of those users have a combined 1M friends? You are going to load 1M users into memory to accept a friend request? I'm telling you how to solve this *class* of problem in a performant, idiomatic way. It might not matter for your *particular* use-case and scale, but take note of the approach denoted above.

Comment: @MyUsername112358 And because you are asking for general advice here about domain modeling, I would feel remiss if I didn't address the underlying issue I see here. That is, it is clear that your domain model was designed according to your *data*, not the desired *behavior*. This is exactly how problems like yours arise - you model the data and then try to "fit in" the behaviors required. It only leads to more problems followed by more questions asking for "design tricks" to help solve them (not to mention a highly procedural codebase). Here's the thing... domain models are *discovered*!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat similar to @user3347715's answer, I would design a `FriendRelationship` aggregate root that contains exactly the data perimeter needed to enforce your invariant. So, load user IDs remote from user1 by up to 2 levels of friendship and check that user2 is not in there.

Note that it is more of a DDD purist approach than @user3347715's solution because the invariant logic will be in the domain layer instead of repository implementation or SQL query. But their answer might well be the more pragmatic one performance wise, depending on the amount of friend data to load at every friend request.

Another approach would be to make the operation eventually consistent with a deduplication background job that boils down direct+indirect friend relations to just an indirect one if the direct one is more recent.

This also questions the notion of friending in the context of your domain. Why do we feel the need to look past the first level of friends? Does it mean a level 2 friend is just as good as a direct friend, for some or all purposes? Could we then store a map of [direct or indirect] friends and get rid of the invariant, making the friending operation idempotent?

So, no silver bullet, only situational answers depending on the business domain, as often.

Comment: You needn't load the data perimeter to enforce the invariant. In general the approach is to *defunctionalize* the process by introducing additional data structures to help mediate the flow. So now we have a new invariant needs to look 2 layers of friends deep? Ok. How can we turn that into data? Simple. Include a new projected field into our `FriendRequest`, say `isIndirectlyFriendsAlready`, that contains the *result* from the calculation required to enforce the invariant. In this way our domain can still be responsible for *enforcing* the rule without being responsible for crunching the data.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's another interesting possibility! Especially if you don't mind that `isIndirectlyFriends` logic is implemented somewhere else than in the domain layer. Can you add that to your answer? Might be what was missing to make OP consider it.